# Jest seems not to be rendering the SVG (but it works in the app)

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I cannot figure this out - I keep getting the following error:

```bash
[{
    "resource": "/Users/daaronch/code/bacalhau/webui/tests/images/jobsIcon.test.tsx",
    "owner": "Jest (bacalhau)",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "renders JobsIcon\n-----\nError: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.\n\nCheck the render method of `AppTest`.",
    "source": "Jest",
    "startLineNumber": 7,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 7,
    "endColumn": 22
}]
```

Here's the MVP reproducible code:

```js
import { render } from "@testing-library/react"
import JobsIcon from "../../src/images/jobs-icon.svg"

export const AppTest = () => <JobsIcon />

test("renders JobsIcon", () => {
  render(<AppTest />)
})
```

(you need to have a real SVG in that directory)

Here's my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "webui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.23.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator": "^7.23.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining": "^7.23.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object": "^7.23.4",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^8.3.1",
    "@fontsource/open-sans": "^5.0.17",
    "@jest/globals": "^29.7.0",
    "@jridgewell/sourcemap-codec": "^1.4.15",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.2.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.45",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1",
    "react-script": "^2.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "wesbos": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build-bacalhau": "cd .. && make build && cd -",
    "start-bacalhau": "cd .. && ./bin/$(go env GOOS)/$(go env GOARCH)/bacalhau serve --web-ui --web-ui-port 3000 && cd -",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test cross-env jest tests/",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "npx eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "npx eslint . --fix",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\", \"tests/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\""
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.8",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-wesbos": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-css-modules-transform": "^4.4.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "wesbos": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - this is the minimum possible that I've seen elsewhere. To be clear, this renders correctly in the app! It's JUST in the test framework.

---

UPDATE: I also tried this as a react component, and it didn't help:

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import { ReactComponent as JobsIcon } from "../../src/images/jobs-icon.svg"

export const AppTest = () => <JobsIcon />

test("renders JobsIcon", () => {
  render(<AppTest />)
})
```

Comment: Are you using CRA? Does changing the import to `import {ReactComponent as JobsIcon} from "../../src/images/jobs-icon.svg"` work? Can you show the import in the working file?

Comment: yep, using CRA - No, switching to that doesn't help :(

Comment: Your config might be wrong - https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#handling-static-assets. Also note that `NODE_ENV=test cross-env jest ...` is definitely the wrong way around.